# How to write all webscraping data in html file using python?

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://gk-hindi.in/gk-questions?page="
i = 1
while i <= 48:
      req = requests.get(url+str(i))
      soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
      mydivs = soup.find("div", {"class": "question-wrapper"})
      print(mydivs)
      with open("output.html", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
            file.write(str(mydivs))
      i = i+1
```

I wanted to save all loop data in a single HTML file but my code save only last loop data.

Answer (score 0):

Open the output file in append mode `a` (assuming that the file already exists, otherwise set `w` mode) **before** webscraping:

```
url = "https://gk-hindi.in/gk-questions?page="
with open("output.html", "a", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    for i in range(1, 49):
        req = requests.get(url + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
        mydivs = soup.find("div", {"class": "question-wrapper"})
        file.write(str(mydivs))
```

Comment: @SiHa, see my prescript

Answer (score -1):

You have to open the file in append mode

```py
with open("output.html", "a", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
  pass
```